# Python script to be string/number when imported

Tags: python, import

I have a file named number.py with a string of text (a number, actually, but I also would like to know how to do this with text strings too please) that I want to be the value of the script when imported.

So if I have another script in the same folder I want the variable number to equal the text/number in the file. So if in that script I go:

```
import number
print number
```

The number would be printed.

What code would I put it number.py to make this happen, I don't plan to run this script, just import it to get that value. I cannot use return outside a function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import *values* you can only import *names* (ie, variables). So in `number.py` you would have a line such as:

```
the_number = 1234
the_string = 'hello world'
```

Now, when you import it:

```
import number
print number.the_number
print number.the_string
```

As [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) is the name of a built-in library, it is best to name your file something else.

---

> Is there a way to not have to go number.x or number.x() I just want
>   the script to equal that number/string.

Its not clear what you are trying to do here "the script to equal that number/string", but if you want to get rid of the `number.` part:

```
from number import the_number, the_string
print(the_number)
print(the_string)
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have to go number.x or number.x() I just want the script to equal that number/string.

Comment: I want the import to have the same effect as "number = 17" so that the variable would be the same if defined that way.

Comment: It will - you need to try it out for yourself. importing a file executes it, so first `numbers.py` will be run, which will execute the line `number = 17`, then you will import this `number` variable so you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file

```
""" This is a file called number.py """
number = 17
```

Then you can import like this:

```
from number import number
print(number) # prints 17
```

In this case, "number" is a module level ("global") variable inside the file "number.py". The naming here get's confusing. The file defines a module-level scope, and you're grabbing the value from that scope

Even better, you could make a function that returns that value

```
global number = 17
def get_number():
    global number
    return number # this is how you use a return statement
```

and from another file

```
from number import get_number
print(get_number())
```

Later down the road, you'll want to not use module-level variables, so when you learn about "classes", a better way would be

```
""" this is a file called number.py """
class Number:
    number = 17
```

and from another class

```
from number import Number
print(Number.number)
```

And quick note: "I cannot use return outside of a function" doesn't mean anything - the keyword "return" is only meaningful in functions - read any tutorial on Python, that's basic and very important

Comment: Is there a way to not have to go number.x or number.x()   I just want the script to equal that number/string.

Comment: yes, in that first example. I edited for clarity - does that make sense? Also see Khalid's note on naming. "number" is not a very good name. The from ... import ... statement grabs the variable and adds it to your local symbol table

Comment: What I mean is "import number;print number" would give the number, not number.number or number.get_number() or having to import as. If this is not possible then the other methods would still be good, but if there was a way to do this, I would like to know. Basically what I want is the equivalent of what return does inside a function, but at the script level.

Comment: And OK I'll rename it

Comment: the from ... import ... is as close as you'll get - "from number import number;print number". Note that this is NOT generally great practice, and while it may seem neater to you right now it is not the most elegant way to solve this problem. There is a fundamental difference between functions and separate files. For a small project, this approach is probably fine though :)

Comment: you might also consider just storing the value in a file somewhere (not a python script, just a boring old file) and reading the file value in. IO is super easy in python

Comment: I just want to hard code a number that's hard to remember, and I know will never change. Using import and as will suffice, it's not that big of a deal, just wanted to know for the sake of knowing.

Comment: And the other information you posted should be a good read when I get time.